# Qt freezing cause of the loop?

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt4

I have designed a gui with PYQT4. It has two buttons. One of start button. It starts a start.py file. And another button execute stop.py file that stop start.py pid.

This start.py and stop.py files are on a remote location. I am connecting there with ssh and paramiko.

When I click to start button, gui is freezing and never answering. I can only get rid of the situation by closing the program . I know the problem. Because  there is a while loop in start.py and it never ends.

When i click to start button its wait for the while loop.

I want to run start.py and i dont want to wait for the loop. It must be run in background or etc..

What can i do ? I tried to trigger it with another .py file. I used subprocess method. But no success. Still have same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I covered that function in thread. And now its working properly without freeze or lag.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PyQT theading](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Threading,_Signals_and_Slots).
You can also use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) if you are using python3.

Comment: I use python 2.7. If its possible I want to do this on remote location. Not on gui.

Comment: @Murat This is not a good idea, you are spawning a full python interpreter for each task.